# Java URLClassloder Hanging

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime, urlclassloader

I have multiple compiled Java class files from various packages in a directory, like so.

> C:/classes/package/A.class
>
> C:/classes/package/B.class
>
> C:/classes/package/subpackage/C.class
>
> C:/classes/package/subpackage/D.class

I'm attempting to load them using a URLClassloader like so.

```
URLClassloder classloader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("C:/classes/").toURI().toURL()});
System.out.println("Loading classes...");
classloader.loadClass("package.A");
classloader.loadClass("package.B");
classloader.loadClass("package.subpackage.C");
classloader.loadClass("package.subpackage.D");
System.out.println("Loaded classes.");
```

This code runs fine until I try to load "package.subpackage.D". The program permanently hangs.

Changing the order in which the classes were loaded had no effect but, after much experimentation, I found that any class extending a native class would cause such a hang, "native" referring to all classes already within the runtime.

So here are my questions:

> Is this the right way to load classes during runtime?
>
> Is there a fix to the problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A quick `jstack` or ^Z/^break should show where the hang is.

Comment: I already know where the hang occurs and have found the correlation between extending native classes and the hang; is there any documentation regarding this?

Comment: I mean where in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `URLClassLoader` needs a parent which knows how to load the JDK classes. The parent loader should probably be borrowed from the context, i.e.:

```
new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader())
```

See [`URLClassLoader(URL[], ClassLoader)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5B%5D,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29).